# Solving a Large band system using Gauss-Seidel Iteration

Tags: matrices, matlab, systems-of-equations

Sorry for my english. I have to solve the following band system using Gauss-seidel iteration program in matlab.

$$  \begin{array}{cccccc}
        12x_1&-2x_2&+x_3&&&=&5\\
        -2x_1&+12x_2&-2x_3&+x_4&&=&5\\
        x_1&-2x_2&+12x_3&-2x_4&+x_5&=&5\\
        x_2&-2x_3&+12x_4&-2x_5&+x_6&=&5\\
        \vdots &\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&&\vdots\\
        x_{46}&-2x_{47}&+12x_{48}&-2x_{49}&+x_{50}&=&5\\
        & x_{47}&-2x_{48}&+12x_{49}&-2x_{50}&=&5\\
        &&x_{48}&-2x_{49}&+12x_{50}&=&5\\
     \end{array}
$$
I already have the algorithm: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=NrkE1TL1 . But I don't know how to proceed. any ideas? thanks.

Comment: Hello and welcome. Can you describe your mathematical problem in greater detail? The code seems to be correct, even if disregarding the sparsity structure, the matrix is diagonally dominant,...

Comment: Hi, I already know how to proceed. it was not a big deal, I just had to complete the matriz with an algorithm and introduce it in my program. but thank you anyway.